# Google Sign In button not working properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, google-oauth, google-signin

`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`
I am using this script in my react app but facing two problems
1.sometimes after reloading, the sign in button gets dissapeared, and then I need to paste the url on a different tab to get it back
2. If I sign in with an account first, then sign in with another account, al though I get all the info of the second account but the google button displays the firstly signed in user email address

```
useEffect(() => {
    /* global google */
    console.log(window.google,process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
    if (window.google) {
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        callback: handleGoogle,
      });
      console.log(google.accounts.id," odddddddddd")
      google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("signUpDiv"), {
        // type: "standard",
        theme: "filled_black", 
        // size: "small",
        text: "continue_with",
        shape: "pill",
      });

      // google.accounts.id.prompt()
    }
  }, [handleGoogle]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clearly visualizing your context, but I have some advice that you should check out your configuration on console.cloud.google.com. Check your Client ID that is correct or not, also check the "Authorized JavaScript origins", you should add both your local host URL with port you are using.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylQF2.png)

Your second problem maybe because of the email of the user who signed in previously can cause when the button fails to update its status correctly. To resolve this, it's important to confirm that you clear the previous user's data before displaying the new user's details. Make certain that the handleGoogle function effectively manages user information and adjusts the component's state as required.

If you still encounter difficulties with the button displaying the incorrect user's email, it could be advantageous to review your handleGoogle function to ensure it correctly handles the clearing and updating of user information.